# using loops and method islower in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert lower case t where ever it occurs to upper case t.

I'm getting an error though.  Heres my code.

```
string1 = 'timbucktwo'
t = 't'
while t.islower in string1:

    print(string1, t.isupper())
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is fairly simple, and if you step back from the upper/lower-case issue it's just "replace 't' with 'T'". You can do this using:

```
string1.replace('t', 'T')
```

Comment: Let me try this again. :^)  The loop won't execute because t.islower is the method, and 'x in some_string' requires x to be a string, and so a TypeError is raised.

Comment: Yep, I was being hasty and not thinking it through. Edited my answer to just ignore that, as your analysis is correct :)

Comment: You would need to set string1 each time equal to the string returned by 'replace'. Otherwise, if string1 originally contained a 't', it would loop infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have:

```
string1 = 'timbucktwo'
while 't' in string1:
    string1 = string1.replace('t', "T")
    print(string1)
```